# How to add custom parser to feedjira?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, feedjira

I have a xml feed in format like this:

```
<league country="england">
 <match status="15:00" time="15:00">
   <home name="Newcastle Utd"/>
   <away name="Norwich"/>
  </match>
    <match status="15:00" time="15:00">
    <home name="Newcastle Utd"/>
    <away name="Norwich"/>
    </match>
    <match status="19:00" time="19:00">
    <home name="Swansea"/>
    <away name="Stoke City"/>
    </match>
 </league>
```

How can I add a custom parser in feedjira and use it for this feed? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'feedjira';
require './Custom.rb';
c = Feedjira::Feed.parse_with Custom::Custom, '<xml><title>TitlePArsed</title></xml>'
print c.title;
```

Custom.rb:

```
require 'feedjira';
module Custom
 # Parser for dealing with Atom feeds.
 class Custom
   include SAXMachine
   include Feedjira::FeedUtilities
   element :title

   def self.able_to_parse?(xml) #:nodoc:
      true
   end

   def url
     @url || (links - [feed_url]).last || links.last
   end

   def feed_url
     @feed_url ||= links.first
   end

   def self.preprocess(xml)
     Preprocessor.new(xml).to_xml
   end
 end
end
```